# Data compression methods

Tags: c++, algorithm, compression

Why are most data compression algorithms created with C++ or Java. Why not use javascript or even ruby? Is it dependent on the file type you are trying to compress such as text,video or even audio files?

Comment: You need a language that easily manipulates bits.  Java is not a good choice.

Comment: Compression algorithms are implementation language neutral. You could implement them in Ruby or Javascript if you wanted to. I don't think the question is "why *not* use Javascript/Ruby", but more about "why *should/would* we use  Javascript/Ruby"? I can't immediately think of a good reason why you would want to implement a data compression algorithm in Javascript for example.

Comment: It is a neat exercise to implement https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding in your favorite language.

Comment: Okay what language would manipulate bits well? I thought java would be a good choice, but as you stated it isn't one. Would C++ be ?

Comment: C excels in bit/byte awareness.

Comment: Thank you for the information. Here

Comment: Have a look at [this related question](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/317398/183949) of my own.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to compress data, it is probably because you have a *lot* of data; as such, the performance of such algorithms is pretty important, and other things being equal, a compiled language typically performs better on the kind of low-level data manipulation such algorithms employ than an interpreted one.

Comment: Most compression libraries are probably written in C given their history and the need for portability.

Comment: Okay thank you for the help I'll do a little more research before coming back again. Data compression is a very cool topic. Thanks again